# Concatenate two CSV files horizontally

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

So I have two textfiles, "pt1.txt" and "pt2.txt"

Contents of "pt1.txt":

```
Name,ICO,Max,USD_ROI
Bitcoin,0.0,19535.7,N/A
Ethereum,0.0,1389.18,N/A
Ripple,0.0,3.6491,N/A
Bitcoin Cash,0.0,4091.7,N/A
EOS,0.99,21.4637,2068.05%
Cardano,0.0,1.27977,N/A
Stellar,0.0,0.851652,N/A
```

Contents of "pt2.txt":

```
BTC_ROI,ETH_ROI
N/A,N/A
N/A,N/A
N/A,N/A
N/A,N/A
N/A,N/A
-260.77%,-130.75%
N/A,N/A
N/A,N/A
```

I want to combine "pt1.txt" and "pt2.txt" by adding the contents of "pt2.txt" into "pt1.txt"

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

f = open("pt1.txt","w+")
df = pd.read_csv("pt2.txt")
f.write(df["BTC_ROI"])
f.write(df["ETH_ROI"])
```

I got an error saying this:

```
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not Series
```

How can I change my code so "pt1.txt" will end up looking like this?

```
Name,ICO,Max,USD_ROI,BTC_ROI,ETH_ROI
Bitcoin,0.0,19535.7,N/A,N/A,N/A
Ethereum,0.0,1389.18,N/A,N/A,N/A
Ripple,0.0,3.6491,N/A,N/A,N/A
Bitcoin Cash,0.0,4091.7,N/A,N/A,N/A
EOS,0.99,21.4637,2068.05%,-260.77%,-130.75%
Cardano,0.0,1.27977,N/A,N/A,N/A
Stellar,0.0,0.851652,N/A,N/A,N/A
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to add columns to an existing CSV. The simplest way to do that would be to read both frames into memory, `concat`, and then dump them.

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('pt1.txt')
df2 = pd.read_csv('pt2.txt')

(pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
  .to_csv('pt2.txt', index=False, na_rep='N/A')
)
```

This is the easiest thing to do if your data is small enough.

Comment: @j.doe crud, that's my bad. Try one more time. It SHOULD work now.